# How do you programmatically add a margin layout rule?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an imageView as a child of a RelativeLayout within a layout xml and am trying to add an equivalent programatically.

I can map `layout_below` to `LayoutParams.addRule(BELOW, textView2)` and `layout_centerHorizontal` to `LayoutParams.addRule(CENTER_HORIZONTAL, TRUE)`

But how does the `layout_marginTop="30p"` get added as a rule programatically?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2d62ff"
    android:id="@+id/rippleLayout2"
    android:layout_weight="0.91">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="top text"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/pizzahut"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` is-a [`MarginLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) and it has various `setMargins()` overloads and public `{top,left,right,bottom}Margin` fields.

Answer (score 0):

Set margins for top like so:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams =  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.setMargins(0, 80, 0, 0);
```